# How to get Product Attribute Options by attribute code in Magento 2.0

Tags: php, magento-2.0

I am trying to retrieve the list of dropdown attributes and check if the value exists (if it does i need to get the value and assign it to the product) and if it doesnt i will have to create it and get its value to assign it to the product.

```
$attribute = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute');
$attributeId = $attribute->getIdByCode('catalog_product','manufacturer');
$model = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute');
$model->load($attributeId);
print_r($model->getFrontendLabel());
```

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: yeah sure ., please check now

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Following Magento 2 guidelines, you **should not use ObjectManager** by yourself. Instead, you must use dependency injection. [More info here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html)

In your Block/Controller/Helper..., create a constructor and inject `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface` class. For example :

```
private \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $productAttributeRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $productAttributeRepository
) {
    $this->productAttributeRepository = $productAttributeRepository;
}
```

Then, in your dedicated method, you want to call *(PHPDoc added for clarity)* :

```
/** @var \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterface[] $manufacturerOptions */
$manufacturerOptions = $this->productAttributeRepository->get('manufacturer')->getOptions();
```

You can now get options values and labels this way :

```
foreach ($manufacturerOptions as $manufacturerOption) {
    $manufacturerOption->getValue();  // Value
    $manufacturerOption->getLabel();  // Label
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('movement')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);?>
```

$_product is the object of Product
The above code returns attribute value of attribute name "movement".

Answer (score 1):

Using API Service layer, for EAV Attribute of any entity type, Inject the service data member in your constructor as follow.

```
protected $eavAttributeRepository;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface $eavAttributeRepositoryInterface,
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->eavAttributeRepository = $eavAttributeRepositoryInterface;
    ...
}
```

And the you can get the attribute using this.

```
$attribute = $this->eavAttributeRepository->get('catalog_product', 'attribute_code_here');
// vardump($attribute->getData());
```

In order to get attribute option values array, use this.

```
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

Comment: This is very helpful, and to add on to this for anyone else looking, if you want to get the attribute code by label,if you get the attribute using the above method then you can do this to get the individual attribute code:
$attributeCodeId = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId('Attribute Label');

Answer (score 1):

```
Try the following code

$attribute_code = "coffe_type";
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$eavConfig = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product',$attribute_code );

$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
foreach($options as $option) {
    $optionsExists[] = array('label' => $option['label'], 'value'=> $option['value'] );
}

print_r($optionsExists);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject an instance of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository` in your constructor (in a block, helper class or wherever):

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $_productAttributeRepository
 */
protected $_productAttributeRepository;

/**
 * ...
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $productAttributeRepository
 * ...
 */
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $productAttributeRepository,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_productAttributeRepository = $productAttributeRepository;
    ...
}
```

Then create a method in your class to get the attribute by code:

```
/**
 * Get single product attribute data 
 *
 * @return Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface
 */
public function getProductAttributeByCode($code)
{
    $attribute = $this->_productAttributeRepository->get($code);
    return $attribute;
}
```

You can then call this method like so, e.g. inside a .phtml file

```
$attrTest = $block->getProductAttributeByCode('test');
```

Then you can make calls on the attribute object, e.g.

1. Get options: `$attrTest->getOptions()`
2. Get frontend label for each store: `$attrTest->getFrontendLabels()`
3. Debug the data array: `echo '> ' . print_r($attrTest->debug(), true);`

> debug: Array (
>       [attribute_id] => 274
>       [entity_type_id] => 4
>       [attribute_code] => product_manual_download_label
>       [backend_type] => varchar
>       [frontend_input] => text
>       [frontend_label] => Product Manual Download Label
>       [is_required] => 0
>       [is_user_defined] => 1
>       [default_value] => Product Manual Download
>       [is_unique] => 0
>       [is_global] => 0
>       [is_visible] => 1
>       [is_searchable] => 0
>       [is_filterable] => 0
>       [is_comparable] => 0
>       [is_visible_on_front] => 0
>       [is_html_allowed_on_front] => 1
>       [is_used_for_price_rules] => 0
>       [is_filterable_in_search] => 0
>       [used_in_product_listing] => 0
>       [used_for_sort_by] => 0
>       [is_visible_in_advanced_search] => 0
>       [position] => 0
>       [is_wysiwyg_enabled] => 0
>       [is_used_for_promo_rules] => 0
>       [is_required_in_admin_store] => 0
>       [is_used_in_grid] => 1
>       [is_visible_in_grid] => 1
>       [is_filterable_in_grid] => 1
>       [search_weight] => 1 )

Comment: Any Idea How to load all attributes using productAttributeRepository?
I want collection of attributes but with all this options you showed.